# HTML tags' placement change using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to make a swap button or any button whenever it is clicked, tags' placement changes.

For example,

```
<p id="1">h11</p>
<p id="2">h22</p>
<p id="3">h33</p>
```

Whenever the up button is clicked, it becomes

```
<p id="2">h22</p>
<p id="1">h11</p>
<p id="3">h33</p>
```

Whenever the down button is clicked, it becomes

```
<p id="1">h11</p>
<p id="3">h33</p>
<p id="2">h22</p>
```

Is it possible to swap the tags' placement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little goofy since there isn't an `insertAfter` method.

```js
function move(id, direction) {
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  let next = el.nextElementSibling == null ? null : el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
  let prev = el.previousElementSibling;

  if (direction === 'down') {
    el.parentElement.insertBefore(el, next);
  } else {
    if (prev) el.parentElement.insertBefore(el, prev);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div id="1">h11</div>
  <div id="2">h22</div>
  <div id="3">h33</div>
  <div id="4">h44</div>
  <div id="5">h55</div>
  <div id="6">h66</div>
</div>
<button onclick="move('1', 'down')">Down</button>
<button onclick="move('1', 'up')">Up</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box for changing the order of elements

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-item {
  order: 2;
}
.second-item {
  order: 3;
}
.third-item {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="first-item">I'm first</div>
  <div class="second-item">I'm second</div>
  <div class="third-item">I'm third</div>
</div>
```

So you will need the only change the class name.